# Allow an input textField in the format of c1/c2/c3...cn

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

1. A textbox that takes an input in the format of: **c1/c2/c3/...cn**
2. if a user wants to enter a value for *c1* and *c3* but not *c2* : **c1//c3/...cn**
   or **/c2/c3/...cn** if user wants to skip *c1* or **c1/c2/c3/** if user wants to skip *cn*
3. user can nullify a value : **c1/NULL/c3/...cn**

please provide a valid validation to restrict above scenarios

Comment: What have you tried? Sounds like you want other people to do your work/homework for you.

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow. StackOverflow is **not** a free code service. Please read the following howtos in order to understand how to ask a question to get an answer rather than to be preached at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var valuesArray:Array = textFeild.text.split("/")
//c1 = valuesArray[0]
//c2 = valuesArray[1]
//c3 = valuesArray[2]
//...
```

If you want the user to specify a null value with "NULL", after making the valuesArray use for instance:

```
if(valuesArray[0] == "NULL"){
    valuesArray[0] = null;
}
```